# Check if the position is a valid cell in a maze

Tags: c++, maze

I am trying to make a maze. The walls consist of '#' and I want to make a path from top left to bottom right using '.'.  I have come this far, However when I run it now I get a segmentation fault and nothing happens. Anyone know what I am doing wrong? I think my problems lie with my recursive function. Be my guest to edit it! Thanks in advance! :D

````
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>

#define North 0
#define East 1
#define South 2
#define West 3

class Maze {
    private:
        int mazeHeight;
        int mazeWidth;
        int seedValue;
        std::vector <std::vector <char>> Maze;
    public:
        void checkuserInput(int Input1, int Input2);
        void mazeConstructor(int x, int y, int z, std::vector <std::vector <char>> vect);
        std::vector <std::vector <char>> initializeMaze();
};

class Path {
    private:
        std::vector <std::vector <char>> Grid;
        bool visited;
        int Height;
        int Width;
    public:
        void pathConstructor(std::vector <std::vector <char>> Maze, int mazeHeight, int mazeWidth);
        bool checkValid(int yPos, int xPos);
        void findPath(int yPos, int xPos);
        void printMaze();
};

// Check if user input is valid
void checkUserInput(int Input1, int Input2) {
    int Height;
    int Width;
    if (!(Input1 >> Height)) {
        throw std::runtime_error ("Invalid input");
    }
    if (!(Input2 >> Height)) {
        throw std::runtime_error ("Invalid input");
    }
} 
//Make the variables accesible
void Maze::mazeConstructor(int x, int y, int z, std::vector <std::vector <char>> vect) {
    mazeHeight = x;
    mazeWidth = y;
    seedValue = z;
    Maze = vect;
}
// Initialize the outer walls with '#'
std::vector <std::vector <char>> Maze::initializeMaze() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mazeWidth; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mazeHeight; j++) {
            Maze[i][j] = '#';
        }
    }
    return Maze;
}
// Make the variables accessible
void Path::pathConstructor(std::vector <std::vector <char>> Maze, int mazeHeight, int mazeWidth) {
    Grid = Maze;
    Height = mazeHeight;
    Width = mazeWidth;
}

bool Path::checkValid(int yPos, int xPos) {
  if(xPos >= Width || xPos < 0) {
      return false;
  } 
  if(yPos >= Height || yPos < 0) {
      return false;
  }
  if (Grid[xPos][yPos] == '#') {
     return false;
  }
  return true;
} 

// Find a path using recursion
void Path::findPath(int yPos, int xPos) {
    if (yPos == Height || xPos == Width) {
        printMaze();
    }
    else {
        Grid[yPos][xPos] = '.';
        int randomNumber = rand() % 3; 
        switch (randomNumber) {
            case South:
                if (checkValid(yPos, xPos)) {
                findPath(yPos + 1, xPos);
                }
                else {
                    findPath(yPos, xPos);
                }
            case East:
                if (checkValid(yPos, xPos)) {
                findPath(yPos, xPos + 1);
                }
                else {
                    findPath(yPos, xPos);
                }
            case North:
                if (checkValid(yPos, xPos)) {
                findPath(yPos - 1, xPos); 
                }
                else {
                    findPath(yPos, xPos);
                }
            case West:
                if (checkValid(yPos, xPos)) {
                findPath(yPos, xPos - 1); 
                }
                else {
                    findPath(yPos, xPos);
                } 
        }   
    }
} 

// Output the maze
void Path::printMaze() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Grid.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Grid[0].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << Grid[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

// Get command line arguments 
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Maze maze;
    Path Path;
    srand (time(0));
    int Height;
    int Width;
    int seedValue;
    Height = atoi(argv[2]);
    Width = atoi(argv[2]);
    try {
        checkUserInput(Height, Width);
    }
    catch(std::runtime_error& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (argc > 3) {
        seedValue = atoi(argv[3]);
    } else {
        seedValue = rand();
    }
    std::vector <std::vector <char>> Maze (Height * 3 + 1, std::vector <char> (Width * 5 + 1, ' '));
    maze.mazeConstructor(Height, Width, seedValue, Maze);
    Path.pathConstructor(maze.initializeMaze(), Height, Width);
    Path.printMaze();
    Path.findPath(1, 1);
}```
````

Comment: I could not exactly understand the problem. The checkValid is always returning true, could this be the issue ?

Comment: No I just returned true so that the program wouldnt crash, it's a FIXME

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried using a lot of if statements, but it ended up looking very ugly and not working (i.e if(yPos == 1 && xPos == 1) { Do something })

Comment: Would you not just check if the X, Y provided is equal to ‘ ’? You aren’t generating a maze yet and your modulo 3 is never going to generate the West direction so it’s hard to know how you plan on doing this.

Comment: What do you mean? :D
But yes indeed, that is the problem, I don't how I can make a maze out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square will be invalid if

1. Its x,y position is outside the maze.
2. Its x,y position is a brick

```
bool Path::checkValid(int yPos, int xPos) {
  if(xPos >= mazeWidth || xPos < 0){
      return false;
  } 

  if(yPos >= mazeHeight || yPos < 0){
      return false;
  }

  if(Maze[xPos][yPos] == '#'){
     return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you just need to check if the position is within the bounds of the maze and that it's a valid "cell".

To check for the validity of the cell, just compare the character you're storing against whatever it is you're using as empty.

To check the position is inside the maze, all you need to do is ensure the y value and x value are within the range [0, mazeHeight) and [0, mazeWidth) respectively. A simple pseudocode function might be this:

```
function checkValid(yPos, xPos)
    // Check that yPos is valid
    if yPos < 0 or yPos >= mazeHeight
        return false

    // Check that xPos is valid
    if xPos < 0 or xPos >= mazeWidth
        return false

    // At this point, you know the location is inside the maze
    // so just check it's an empty square
    return Maze[yPos][xPos] == ' ' // Assuming ' ' is empty
```

Hopefully this helps!

====================== EDIT ======================

Just a couple extra points about your code:

In your findPath function, you're using `rand() % 3` when there are 4 possible outcomes (0, 1, 2, 3). `rand() % 3` will wrap *at 3*, so you'll get something like this: [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, ...] if rand() were to generate [1, 2, 3, 4, ....]

Reading your code more carefully, I believe checkUserInput is the issue. You are comparing (want to be comparing) the inputs against the width and height -- this is not what the code is doing:

```cpp
// Check if user input is valid
void checkUserInput(int Input1, int Input2) {
    int Height; // Create a variable called height -- no initial value
    int Width; // Create a variable called width-- no initial value
    if (!(Input1 >> Height)) { // ???? -- See below
        throw std::runtime_error ("Invalid input");
    }
    if (!(Input2 >> Height)) { // Again, see below
        throw std::runtime_error ("Invalid input");
    }
}
```

To check the value, you're using the following condition: `!(Input1 >> Height)`. What I believe you *want* to do is `Input1 <= Height`. The operator `>>` is not a greater than operation, it's a bit-wise left-shift, which results in you halving the number. (Also, generally speaking you should just use less than or equal (`<=`) instead of inverting the output of greater than

The cause of the segfault, however, is the uninitialized variables. C++ has created a little pocket of memory for them within your program, but has not yet filled that space with something meaningful. You need to set the variable to something (initialize it) with the `=` operator.

How you choose to fix this is up to you, but I would suggest just using the `mazeHeight` and `mazeWidth` member variables in the class

Comment: This did help a lot, thanks for that! However the program crashes with segmentation fault when I run it, any idea where that's coming from?

Comment: And when you run your program in your debugger, what does your debugger show you for the location of the segmentation fault? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself.

Comment: @Jojo I'm not sure why it would crash with a segmentation fault, of all things. Are you sure you're running it in Debug mode (as opposed to Release)? My best guess is that you're not correctly constructing the Maze vector (also, I highly advise you not to have a class variable with the same name as the class -- it'll lead to a lot of confusion and weird issues). There are also a couple other issues I've found in the code which probably aren't causing the issue, but won't give you the right answer